# Capitalizing "U" in "United States"

Tags: history, capitalization, proper-nouns

Is it true that until the Civil War we did not capitalize the *U* in *United States*?

Comment: I think the U was always capitalized, but it was once common, some say before the Civil War, to say [*the United States are*, instead of the United States *is*.](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/002663.html)

Comment: Did you mean to ask *during* the Civil War?  Just curious.

Answer (score 5):

The first two lines of the Declaration of Independence are:

> **IN CONGRESS, July 4, 1776.**
>
> **The unanimous Declaration of the thirteen united States of America,**

The first two lines Article I of the Articles of Confederation of 1781 are:

> **ARTICLE I**
>
> **The Stile of this Confederacy shall be "The United States of America".**

So *united* was initially not capitalized, but *United States* with capitalization was adopted when the Articles were ratified in 1781.

Perhaps you're confusing the Articles of Confederation (**confederacy**: "a league or compact between two or more persons, bodies of men, or states for mutual support or common action" [M-W Unabridged]) with the secession of the Confederated States of America, which precipitated the Civil War.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just a New Zealander/Englander but after reading bits of it I think the capitalisation is all over the place - which indicates that possibly there were all forms of writing it at the time.

So it's possible that there were conventions all over the country and the world that where not the same.

Comment: A quick google check shows that in what appears to be the original, "united" is, indeed, uncapitalized, and is written in a significantly smaller hand than "States": http://www.standupamericaus.org/sua/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/declaration_big_enhanced.jpg

Comment: hahaha - I was recalling it from my last visit years ago! Yes I think I'm wrong.

Comment: Sorry, but this should rather be a comment.